# Javascript MongoDB dot notation issue for embedded document

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I am using MongoDB with Javascript. I am trying to declare the following parameters:

```
params = {
  title: title,
  description: description,
  "media.image": image,
  feedUpdated: new Date()
};
```

Then I run a the query using a Service that includes the use of $set as follows:

```
collection.update({
    _id: ObjectId(id)
  }, {
    $set: {
      params
    }
  }, function(e, updated) {
    cb(e, updated);
  });
```

But I get the following error:

> MongoError: The dotted field 'media.image' in 'params.media.image' is not valid
>   for storage.

I think the issue is due to the fact that by declaring the object using quotes it declares it as an object key "media.image" instead of leaving it as a string. According to MongoDB **$set** documentation:

> To specify a  in an embedded document or in an array, use dot
>   notation.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/

I could technically write manually the query to include 'media.image' but I would prefer to declare it in the params and pass it to the Service.

Any ideas? All approaches are welcome!

Comment: That's a JavaScript error. What you mean is `$set: params`. When you do `$set: { params }` it gets expanded as applying `"params"` as the name of the key for the object. Much the same as writing `'$set': { 'params': params }`, which of course you do not want. `params` is already an object. You don't need to wrap it in one.

Comment: Yes you're right! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not allowed to use dots in keys while working with MongoDB. I can suggest two approaches:

```
// #1 camelCase
params = {
  title: title,
  description: description,
  mediaImage: image,
  feedUpdated: new Date()
}

// #2 object
params = {
  title: title,
  description: description,
  media: { image: image },
  feedUpdated: new Date()
}
```

Comment: To specify a <field> in an embedded document or in an array, use dot notation. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/

Comment: Not the issue. What the OP is trying to do "dot notation" wise is perfectly valid. The actual problem is a misunderstanding of JavaScript syntax.

Comment: I've got it now, thanks. I thought OP is trying to update `params` field.

Answer (score 0):

With JavaScript, thanks to ECMAScript 2015 computed property names, you can use dot notation by adding brackets [] around the key in question. In your case, it would be:

```
params = {
  title: title,
  description: description,
  ["media.image"]: image,
  feedUpdated: new Date()
};
```